# value of $g(2019)$ in functional Inequality

Tags: functions

> Suppose the function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies the inequality
>
> $\displaystyle \bigg|\sum^{n}_{r=1}3^{r}\bigg(g(x+ry)-g(x-ry)\bigg)\bigg|\leq 1$ for all positive integer $n$ amd all real values of $x,y$
>
> If value of $g(13)=17.$ Then  value of $g(2019)$ is

what i try

$$\bigg|\sum^{n}_{r=1}3^{r}\bigg(g(x+ry)-g(x-ry)\bigg)\bigg|\leq 1$$

replace $n\rightarrow (n-1)$

$$\bigg|\sum^{n-1}_{r=1}3^{r}\bigg(g(x+ry)-g(x-ry)\bigg)\bigg|\leq 1$$

Subtracting theses two equation

$$\bigg|3^{n}\bigg(g(x+ny)-g(x-ny)\bigg)\bigg|\leq 1$$

$$\bigg|\bigg(g(x+ky)-g(x-ky)\bigg)\bigg|\leq \frac{1}{3^{n}}$$

How do i solve it , Help me please

Comment: The constant function $g(x) = 17$ satisfies the inequality. If the answer is unique, then $g(2019) = 17$...

Comment: Yes achille hue answer is unique. Please explain me i did not understand . Thanks

Comment: $|a|<1$ and $|a+b|<1$ does not imply $b<1$. Indeed set $a=-\frac34$ and $b=\frac32$.

Comment: If $|a|<1$ and $|b|<1$. Then $|a-b|<1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|g(x+t)-g(x-t)| \leq \frac 2 {3^{t/y}}$ for all $t >0$ and for all real $y$ such that $\frac t y$ is a positive integer.  Let $y \to 0$ through the sequence $(\frac t 1, \frac t 2,\frac t 3...)$ to conclude that $g(x+t)=g(x-t)$ for all real $x$ and all $t>0$. Can you deduce from this that $g$ is a constant?

Comment: Thanks Kavi Rama can you please explain me how can i deduce constant function from $g(x+t)=g(x-t)$ Thanks

Comment: For every positive number $t$, $2t$ is a period of $g$. Does that ring a bell?

Comment: Using $x\rightarrow (x+t)$ Yes i got $g(x+2t)=g(x)$ Now how can i solve further

Comment: If $x<y$ the you can write $y$ as $x+2t$ for some positive number $t$. What can you conclude now?

Comment: @LutzL I missed  $2$ in the numerator. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: Thanks Kavi Rama Murthy Got it.